# Apache config - how to enable additional ports

Tags: server, apache2, proxy, lamp, 17.04

After installing mu LAMP stack. I have port 80 running by default athttp://127.0.1.1/

Now I want to add new ports, eg 8000, 8888.

How can I add them in my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf in my Ubuntu 17.04?

This is how I do it in **Arch Linux**:

2.2 In /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, uncomment the following two lines for Proxy:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

2.3 Don't forget to add Port 443 to your listen ports in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

```
Listen 443
Listen 8888
```

2.3 Add these blocks:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName www.xxxx.co.uk
    ServerAlias xxxx.co.uk
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3838/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3838/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.co.uk/fullchain.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx.co.uk/privkey.pem"
</VirtualHost>
```

What about the Apache in Ubuntu?

I don't even see:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

in apache2.conf in my Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Ubuntu Xenial:

1. Add additional ports in the `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` like so:

   ```
   Listen 80
   Listen 8888
   ```
2. Now in your `VirtualHost` file add that port like so:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80 *:8888>

      ....
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Restart apache2:

   ```
   sudo apache2ctl restart
   ```